# How can I pass an attribute parameter type with List<string> in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I pass a List to a construtor?

It shows a message:

Error   14  An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {
    private List<string> multipleProgramID;

    //constructor
    public CustomAuthorize(List<string> _multipleProgramID) {
        multipleProgramID = _multipleProgramID;
    }
}

[CustomAuthorize(new List<string>(new string[] { ProgramList.SURVEY_INPUT, ProgramList.SURVEY_OUTPUT } ))]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteWaterQualityItems(string sourceID, string wqID) {
    // ..other code...
}

public class ProgramList {
    public const string SURVEY_INPUT = "A001";
    public const string SURVEY_INPUT = "A002";
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem isn't passing a `List<string>` to a constructor *in general* - the problem is that you're trying to use it for an *attribute*. You basically can't do that, because it's not a compile-time constant.

It looks like `ProgramList` is effectively an enum - so you might want to make it an enum instead:

```
 [Flags]
 public enum ProgramLists
 {
     SurveyInput,
     SurveyOutput,
     ...
 }
```

Then make your `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` (which should be named like that, with a suffix of `Attribute`) accept a `ProgramLists` in the constructor. You'd specify it as:

```
[CustomAuthorize(ProgramLists.SurveyInput | ProgramLists.SurveyOutput)]
```

You can then have a separate way of mapping each `ProgramLists` element to a string such as `"A001"`. This could be done by applying an attribute to each element, or maybe having a `Dictionary<ProgramLists, string>` somewhere.

If you *really* want to keep using strings like this, you could make `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` accept a single comma-separated list, or make it an array instead of a list and use a parameter array:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public FooAttribute(params string[] values)
    {
        ...
    }
}

[Foo("a", "b")]
static void SomeMethod()
{
}
```

Comment: in 2020, is this still to way to go?

Comment: @curiousBoy: Yes, attributes still can't use lists.

Comment: And in 2021 I presume it's still the case. If anyone has a better way please add it as an answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use List<T>.

Attributes have restrictions on parameters and property types, because they have to be available at compile-time. [Using attributes in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes#how-to-add-attributes-to-code)

Use an array instead:

```
//constructor
public CustomAuthorize(string[] _multipleProgramID) 
{
    ...
}

// usage
[CustomAuthorize(new string[] { ProgramList.SURVEY_INPUT, ProgramList.SURVEY_OUTPUT })]
```

Comment: The compiler suggests this is possible - but for some reason this exact code (with string rather than enum) didn't work for me :( I got the same error about only being able to use constant expressions, types and array initializers - which is exactly what I was doing! Had to use a string split, as suggested by @blues_driven.

Comment: just tried it and it does compile in VS 2017, but it doesn't have to work for me - it has to work for you :-)

Comment: I was trying to pass a string array argument as a NUnut TestCase parameter. `[TestCase(new string[] {"a"})]
            public void TestMethod(string[] ab)` - this gives me `Error CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`. And I've just worked out why. It couldn't work out which parameter I was trying to pass - If I make an object array WHICH CONTAINS my string array it works: `[TestCase(new object[] { new string[] { "a" } })]`

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do something similar and ended up passing a comma separated `string` and using `string.Spilt(',')` in the attribute constructor to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use "params" keyword in your custom attribute constructor and make your programList "enum"

```
[CustomAttribute(ProgramList.SURVEY_INPUT, ProgramList.SURVEY_OUTPUT)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteWaterQualityItems(string sourceID, string wqID) {
    // ..other code...
}
```

in you custom attribute class use this

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {

//Constructor
public CustomAuthorize (params ProgramList[] programListTypes) {

            multipleProgramID= programListTypes;
        }

private ProgramList[] multipleProgramID;

}
```

and you enum class

```
public enum ProgramList : int
{
SURVEY_INPUT = 001;
SURVEY_OUTPUT =002;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option:

```
   public class ConstraintExpectedValues : ConstraintAttribute
    {

        public ConstraintExpectedValues(object[] expectedValues)
        {
            this.ExpectedValues = expectedValues;
        }

        public object[] ExpectedValues { get; set; }
    }
```

Usage:

```
[ConstraintExpectedValues(new object[] {5,7,9})]
```